# Infinite continued fraction implies that the number is irrational

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

I've read recently that any number with infinite continued fraction is irrational. See this continued fraction below

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued+fraction+of+the+cosine
If I substitute x for $\frac{\pi}{2}$ I will get zero on the left side, but the continued fraction is infinite because its convergent ones never cancel out. Could anyone explain me this?

Comment: Please write down what you think you get when you "substitue $1$ for $\pi/2$". Then we may be able to help you.

Comment: @Somos You're an optimist.

Comment: What does "its convergent ones never cancel out" mean ?

Comment: What you must have read is that a number with an infinite [***simple*** continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleContinuedFraction.html) expansion is irrational. A continued fraction is "simple" if all the partial numerators are ones.

Comment: Any rational number can be expanded as a **simple** continued fraction in two slightly different ways, and those continued fractions are finite. Any irrational number has a unique expansion as a **simple** continued fraction, and it's infinite. (The continued fraction is periodic if and only if the irrational number is quadratic.)

Answer (score 0):

Answered (in general) by [@bof](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/111012/bof) in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511017/infinite-continued-fraction-implies-that-the-number-is-irrational#comment5187903_2511017):

> [...] a number with an infinite [***simple** continued
> fraction*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleContinuedFraction.html)
> expansion is irrational. A continued fraction is "simple" if all the
> partial numerators are ones.