# Simple continued fraction for irrational numbers.

Tags: irrational-numbers, continued-fractions

I read it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511017/infinite-continued-fraction-implies-that-the-number-is-irrational) that: "What you must have read is that a number with an infinite [simple continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleContinuedFraction.html) expansion is irrational. A continued fraction is "simple" if all the partial numerators are ones."

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued%20fraction&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22ContinuedFractionCalculator%22,%20%22number%22%7D%20-%3E%22zeta(5)%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22continued%20fraction%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D) has this simple continued fraction for $\zeta(5):$ $[1;27,12,1,1,15,...]$. But we don't know if $\zeta(5)$ is rational or not, so I understood something wrong.

Comment: I think WA is just giving the first few terms of the simple continued fraction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is we don't know what the "$\ldots$" is.  If it terminates after finitely many terms, $\zeta(5)$ is rational.  If it doesn't, $\zeta(5)$ is irrational.  We (and WA) can compute as many terms as we want by numerical computation, but there's no sign of a pattern.